# Ember js pass id to bind-attr

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to pass a dynamic id to the bind-attr

I have the following template-

```
{{#each attachments}}
  <a {{bind-attr href = attachmentDownloadUrl }} download title='download attachment'>
   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save'> </span>

 </a>


{{/each}}
```

And in the specific controller want to get the current attachment id -

```
attachmentDownloadUrl: function(id){
        console.log(id);
        return "xxx"+id;
    }.property('id'),
```

How do I pass the id ? Thank you

Comment: Quoting from [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/): In addition to normal text, you may also want to have your templates contain HTML elements **whose attributes are bound to the controller**.

Answer (score 1):

You  wouldn't pass an argument to the computed property, but you could create an `itemController` which could make the computed property specific to each item, instead of on the collection.

#### Template

```
{{#each item in attachments itemController='foo'}}
  <a {{bind-attr href=item.attachmentDownloadUrl }} download title='download attachment'>
   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save'> </span>
 </a>
{{/each}}
```

#### Item Controller

```
App.FooController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  attachmentDownloadUrl: function(){
    return "xxx"+this.get('id');
  }.property('id')
});
```

Comment: I used handlebars helper to pass the id and then return the dynamic <a> tag from within the helper. Wanted to know which is a better practice, helpers or item controller ?